# django CMS cant see my toolbar

Tags: django, admin, toolbar, django-cms

Hello I have a common problem in Django like Django can't see ..
OK this time Django can't see my beautiful toolbar.
Terminal doesn't show any error.
This is my cms_toolbar.py placed in my "aktualnosci" folder

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from cms.toolbar_pool import toolbar_pool
from cms.toolbar_base import CMSToolbar
from cms.utils.urlutils import admin_reverse
from .models import *

@toolbar_pool.register

class PollToolbar(CMSToolbar):
    supported_apps = (
        'aktualnosci',
    )
    watch_models = [Aktualnosci]

    def populate(self):
        if not self.is_current_app:
            return

        menu = self.toolbar.get_or_create_menu('poll-app', _('Aktualnosci'))

        menu.add_sideframe_item(
            name=_('Lista aktualnosci'),
            url=admin_reverse('aktualnosci_aktualnosci_changelist'),
        )

        menu.add_modal_item(
            name=_('Dodaj aktualnosc'),
            url=admin_reverse('aktualnosci_aktualnosci_add'),
        )
```

Of course Django can't see it and ignore it.
My question is - how to force Django to see it.
Screaming doesnt help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django CMS >= 3.2, the file should be called cms_toolbars.py instead of cms_toolbar.py